# Module is not available in angularjs + Jasmine Unit testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Module is defined as

```
var $manage = angular.module('manage', [....]);
```

Controller is defined as

```
    $manage.line.events.controller('eventsController', [..., function(...){
$scope.page = "events";
}]);
```

My simple unit test case is

```
describe('Module: manage', function() {
  beforeEach(module('manage'));
  var scope, ctrl, rootScope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('eventsController', {
          $scope: scope
      });
  }));
  it("test page", function () {
        expect(scope.page).toEqual('events');
    });
});
```

Here, i am getting a error like

Failed to instantiate module ampleManage due to.... manage is not available.

I have integrated angular-mocks.js also. Tried so many possibilities but not working for me.

Basic need is .

Need to access controller/scope in test case.

Comment: Try the old fashioned way first; import your module, then angular.mock.module('manage') etc., see if that works first. Instead of looking at scope.page try ctrl.page

Comment: you have add all dependencies in karma conf file which are added in main app

Comment: added all dependencies. still facing same issue like "manage is not available".

Comment: @rrd, I have tried following case. still same

expect(ctrl).toBeDefined();